# Is there an application to slowdown connection intentionally?

Tags: networking

In many development scenarios I needed to see how my application - web or desktop would behave when the internet connection is very slow - 10-15KBps. Is there a way to slow down the internet speed in Ubuntu/Windows/Mac?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked over at [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18038/how-to-limit-internet-speed).  There is, apparently, a walkthrough over at [UbuntuGeek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/use-bandwidth-shapers-wondershaper-or-trickle-to-limit-internet-connection-speed.html).  Though this does seem like overkill...

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac there's a tool that comes with XCode called Network Link Conditioner. You can chose various pre-defined network profiles (eg "3G, Good Connectivity" or "Edge, Lossy Network") or define your own using parameters such as bandwidth, dropped packet percentage, etc and independently for downstream and upstream.